# Menedeley AppImage and the LibreOffice Plug-In?

Tags: mendeley

Using Ubuntu 22.04 and the new version of Mendeley only comes as an AppImage.  Is there a workaround for installing the LibreOffice citation Plug-In toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I also have Ubuntu 22.04.

1. Download an old version of installer from here: https://www.mendeley.com/autoupdates/installers/1.19.8.  I took `Mendeley Desktop 1.19.8 for Linux (64-bit)`
2. Follow this instruction. https://askubuntu.com/a/1077212/1199158 . It is totally valid for 22.04.

**UPDATE**
Having done and trying to use it, I have to state that the system hangs while trying to add a citation and an exported file was not supported as a one having citations by *office 365*.

How about using *Zotero*?

Comment: Yeah, found out that for **most** citation formats, Mendeley still works.  Just don't like ZOTERO's interface.